# "What you think (that) you know ....."

Tags: conjunction-reduction

> What You Think You Know About Human Evolution Is Wrong

This is a title of an online article. My question is, is the conjunction "that" omitted in the title? I think if it weren't omitted, the title would be like this,

> What You Think **That** You Know About Human Evolution Is Wrong

But, I also find it unnatural after adding the conjunction, so I'm pretty confused.

Comment: 'That' could be used, but it isn't wrong to omit it.

Comment: @KateBunting Which one sounds better to you?

Comment: Leaving out _that_ makes for a snappier title, which is why they used it!

Comment: @KateBunting If the sentence weren't a title but rather a sentence in a conversation or a sentence in a page, would leaving out _that_ make them snappier too?

Comment: It would make it less formal.